# Pointer function with an array

Tags: c, pointers

I have a problem, I have a function and I do not understand a specific thing. The function is:

```
int F( int* x , int n ){
    int i , m=0
    for (i=0;i<n; i++){
       m=x[ i ] + m;
    }
    return m * m ;
}
```

I call the function with a pointer and with an integer. Later I do a "for", but I do not understand the line:

```
 m=x[ i ] + m;
```

Because x is a pointer not an array.

Could you please help me.

Then x points to the memory position then to +1. For example if i call the function with

```
n=10
x=&n
F(x,n)
```

the function returns somenthing strange.

X points to the position memory to n, later to the position memory to n+1??

Comment: array indexing works on pointer types as well - arrays and pointers are more-or-less interchangeable

Comment: **x[i]** is equal to **\*(x + i)**

Comment: Then x points to the memory position then to +1. For example i call the function with n=10, x=&n; F(x,n), the function return somenthing strange

Comment: Your example usage is not how `F` is intended to be called...

Comment: How should be called F?

Comment: @SergioOvalle: `x` is an array of integers, but in your last example is just an int.

Comment: Why are you calling a function that you have no idea how to call?

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are represented as contiguous memory and the array variable gets interpreted as a pointer to the base of that memory (e.g. `&(x[0])`). Array offset syntax gets translated into pointer arithmetic.

See this post, which clarifies the [difference between pointer and arrays](http://blogs.perl.org/users/mauke/2012/11/c-programming-what-is-the-difference-between-an-array-and-a-pointer.html):

> [] - indexed dereference 
>   a[b] is equivalent to *(a + b). This means a and b must be a pointer to an array element and an integer; not necessarily respectively, because a[b] == *(a + b) == *(b + a) == b[a]. Another important equivalence is p[0] == 0[p] == *p.

The function might be equivalently declared (with more clarity perhaps):

```
int F(int x[], int n);
```

and you would call it like so:

```
int data[3] = {1, 2, 3};
int value = F(data, 3);
```

Comment: Then n must to be an array ?, because x pointer to x[0] that is n, later points to *(n+1), but in that position there are garbage???

Comment: Yes, in the way that you have shown in the updated question, it is "garbage". You are literally passing in a pointer to a single integer, not an array (or contiguous block of memory that could be treated as an array). `F` intends `x` to be a pointer to a block of memory storing `int`s and `n` to be the length of that array.

Comment: Could you please give me an example to call the function?

Answer (score 0):

Since x is a pointer, when you pass the array to the function, x points to the first element of the array. Since array is a contigous allocation of memory, The pointer can be made to point to consecutive elements of the array. Thats why

```
m=x[i]+m
```

x[i] implies to the `i`th index from the first element of the array

```
main()
{
    int x[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},sum;
    sum=function(x,10);
    return 0;
}
```

This function sends the array to the function, with 10, the size of the array

Comment: Could you please give an example to call de function